# CIA.gov "World FactBook" MySQL?

Tags: content, database

Is the CIA's '[World FactBook](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/)" of statistics and national data available in a MySQL format or some format conducive to parsing and incorporating into a website?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a platform like Kasabi, which provides a SPARQL edpoint to the Factbook data.

- Kasabi: http://kasabi.com/
- Dataset: http://kasabi.com/dataset/cia-world-fact-book
- Drupal tutorial video: http://lin-clark.com/blog/turning-cias-data-pretty-pictures-your-site-using-views

Answer (score 1):

Kasabi doesn't seem to exist any more, but there is a project called [FactbookXML](http://jmatchparser.sourceforge.net/factbook/) that provides a MySQL dump of the CIA factbook.